# microsoft graph api outlook send multiple email individually

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, outlook-api

When sending mail from Outlook, enter multiple recipients for recipients.

When an email is sent, only you are displayed in the recipients.

Can you implement that function through graph api?

If you provide that feature, we would appreciate it if you could share the tutorial.

I want to use this function by adding-in to Outlook.

Comment: In toRecipients property you can enter multiple email Addresses as the toRecipients is an array. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example

Comment: When I add multiple emails and send an email, does the recipient see only my email? Does the function work even if I click the Send button when I do the Outlook AddIn?

Comment: So you mean you don't want to show other emails in `TO` for all individuals?

Comment: @Shiva Keshav Varma That's right, that's what I wanted

Comment: I didn't use any time the outlook-addin anytime but for this kind of scenario you can keep every participant in bccRecipient property and it will work as you said. See if it works.

Comment: Isn't the bcc recipient a BCC, not the recipient?

Comment: Bcc is provided by outlook, but that's not what I want.

Comment: You look for customizing as you dont want to show other emails in To for all individuals. Unfortunately you can't use Microsoft Graph API for your requirement.

Comment: @Dev https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook?view=outlook-js-preview
Is this a function that office.js should not be used for?

Comment: Yes you can use it. But please note that you're calling the above API call from Office.js. It's a different API when compare to Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: @Dev Can you implement that function using office.js? Is it a relevant API?

Comment: I don't think API's will be of help here. Rather you should use [Outlook custom form or Outlook Form Regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/customizing-form-pages-and-form-regions) to see if you customize as you wish and works as you expect. In past, i used it with Outlook for Windows and it worked for my usecase (to add/customize the fields how the form should look like).